# Changing property of an object in an array

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, drupal-7

In drupal's aggregator module, I have an issue with Facebook title item of the RSS feed of a facebook page. The encoding of the text is HTML/unicode equivalent of the characters.

```
&#x62a;&#x62c;&#x631;&#x628;&#x629;
```

I decided using `myTheme_aggregator_block_item(&$item, $feed =0);` in the template.php to handle modification of $item->title using `htmlspecialchars_decode()`.

I wrote a print_r($item) to get know about its structure, it printed out something like the following:

```
Array
(
    [item] => stdClass Object
        (
            [iid] => 16
            [fid] => 1
            [title] => &#x62a;&#x62c;&#x631;&#x628;&#x629; &#x646;&#x635; &#x639;&#x631;&#x628;&#x64a; &#x645;&#x646; &#x627;&#x644;&#x628;&#x62f;&#x627;&#x64a;&#x629; &#x628;&#x62f;&#x648;&#x646; &#x646;&#x635; &#x644;&#x627;&#x62a;&#x64a;&#x646;&#x64a;.
            [link] => http://www.facebook.com/gharibderma/posts/303019283212608
            [author] => Khaled Gharib Derma Clinic
            [description] => ‫تجربة نص عربي من البداية بدون نص لاتيني.‬
            [timestamp] => 1407389794
            [guid] => www.facebook.com/notification/7f39a6557fe0b0857ce28dd9a0b26c13
        )

    [feed] => 0
)
```

I used the following hook:

```
function myTheme_aggregator_block_item(&$item, $feed = 0) {  

  $item['item']->title = htmlspecialchars_decode($item['item']->title).'***';


}
```

In the block of the aggregator, the list of the items becomes blank i.e just the decoration dots of the list without text. And the title of the item in the more page of the aggregator remains as it is with wrong encoding `&#x62a;&#x62c;...`

Here I have got confused: Does it an issue accessing the object's property in its array or does it an issue for returning the modified $item which is referenced in the function?!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's more going on here (I don't use Drupal) but I do know that you need to use `html_entity_decode()` instead of `htmlspecialchars_decode()` to convert those entities:

```
$item['item']->title = html_entity_decode($item['item']->title).'***';
```

Online demo [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6a5051697c637112575bea06e437746e4d4f20b1).